# Old Microsoft Publisher file missing font

Tags: fonts, microsoft-publisher

I have an old Microsoft Publisher file (for about 10 years ago), and when I try to open it, it will give me a warning about a missing font:

> [image: Arial Helvetica Sans-serif]

What is `(Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif)` font? all of them are installed in my fonts. But no success. How to find the exact font?

Comment: “Arial, Helvetica, San-serif” That seems like an HTML font family/hierarchy declaration.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thanks, but how to fix it?

Comment: No idea. But it’s a clue!